# parse_stream doesnt seem to convert my json file to a data frame. The result it gives me is null

Tags: r, json, dataframe, rtweet, rjson

I am tryin to use `parse_stream` to convert a json file to a data frame, it doesnt create the data frame instead it shows up under values in r-studio and it is null.

```
library(rtweet)
library(rjson)

stream_tweets(q='brasil, brazil',timeout = 30,parse=FALSE,file_name = 'stream1.json')
str1<-parse_stream('stream1.json')
View(testdf)
```

[image]